# WPF Custom Control Scrollbar handling

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, scrollbar

I have a custom control derived from UIElement that draws some text in the onrender override. It works great except I can't get any scrollbars to appear when they're needed.

I have this in the xaml

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">                                     
  <local:AViewer BracketColor="LimeGreen" 
</ScrollViewer>
```

And I have overridden MeasureCore to return the actual width/height, but the scrollbars never turn up if the window is sized to be too small.

What else do I need to add to the control to get scrolling to work, do I need to implement IScrollInfo?

TIA

Comment: Please check for heights in UserControl, and insure that you used "Auto" for main Container. also check width and height values for parents of ScrollViewer.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed: I wasn't calling InvalidateMeasure when I was updating the drawing. After calling that everything worked ok.